# Kustomize: How to Reference Name of a Secret Generated by secretGenerator in Deployment When Hash Suffix is Added?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-secrets, configuration-management, kustomize

**Problem Summary**:

I am using Kustomize to generate a secret using **`secretGenerator`**, and I need to reference this secret in a Deployment. Kustomize is appending a unique hash suffix to the secret name, and I'm unable to reference the generated secret by name in my Deployment.

**Previous Approach and Current Challenge**:

In the past, I used **`vars`** to capture the **`metadata.name`** of the secret and place it where needed. Since **`vars`** have been deprecated, I now use replacements, but this approach does not include the necessary hash suffix. From what I've gathered, it seems replacements won't have this functionality either going forward. Disabling the hashing feels like a hack and not best practice. Using Name Reference Transformers seems more static and harder to maintain than the old **`vars`** solution.

**Reproducible Structure**:

A reproducible version of the problem has this struture

```
├── base
│   ├── application
│   │   ├── deployment.yml
│   │   └── kustomization.yml
│   └── secrets
│       ├── kustomization.yml
│       └── my-secret.env
├── components
│   └── replacements_component
│       └── kustomization.yml
└── overlay
    └── instance
        └── kustomization.yml
```

**Code Snippets and Configuration**:

`base/application/deployment.yaml` and `base/application/kustomization.yaml` looks like this:

```
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: test
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: test
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: test
          env:
            - name: test
              value: REPLACE
-----------------------------
resources:
- ./deployment.yml
```

The `base/secrets/kustomization.yaml` looks like this:

```
secretGenerator:
- name: my-secret
  env: my-secret.env
```

The `components/replacements_component/kustomization.yml` looks like this:

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: Component

replacements:
  - source:
      kind: Secret
      name: my-secret
    targets:
      - select:
          kind: Deployment
          name: test
        fieldPaths:
          - spec.template.spec.containers.[name=test].env.[name=test].value
```

This is the overlay kustomization file:

```
namespace: test-deployment

resources:
  - ../../base/application/
  - ../../base/secrets/

components:
  - ../../components/replacements_component
```

**Actual vs Desired Output**:

When **`kustomize build`** is run, I get the following output:

```
apiVersion: v1
data: {}
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: my-secret-46f8b28mk5
  namespace: test-deployment
type: Opaque
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test
  namespace: test-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: test
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: test
          value: my-secret
        name: test
```

This is the desired output:

```
apiVersion: v1
data: {}
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: my-secret-46f8b28mk5
  namespace: test-deployment
type: Opaque
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test
  namespace: test-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: test
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: test
          value: my-secret-46f8b28mk5
        name: test
```

**Questions and Help Needed**:

How can I capture the generated secret name, including the hash suffix, and use it as a replacement in my Deployment? Is there a best practice for handling this scenario without resorting to disabling hashing or using more static solutions?

**EDIT:**
As pointed out it is possible to use the 'valueFrom.secretKeyRef' and 'envFrom.secretRef' in the specific deployment. That would work here specifically but in other cases like this:

```
 volumes:
      - name: my-volume
        azureFile:
          secretName: temp-name
          shareName: temp-shareName
```

It is not possible to use the above mentioned references. Targeting the secret with replacements only gives the non-suffix name of the secret

Comment: Is there any reason to not use `valueFrom.secretKeyRef` or `envFrom.secretRef` in your `Deployment`? If you were using these and hardcoding "my-secret", Kustomize would take care of adding the suffix to the reference.

Comment: You are correct. That would be possible in the specific scenario but when those references cant be used I still miss vars old functionality. I've edited the post to include another scenario where there issue would arise